# preg_match(): No ending delimite

Tags: preg-match

My website shows the following error when host updates the php version

**Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found in**

in the following code:

```
<?php
   $mid_str = " and mid != '0' and ";
   if($_REQUEST['search']){
    mysql_select_db($database_myconn, $myconn);
    $query_spages = "SELECT id, url, title, description, keywords, active, ip, catID, exp, pdate,
                   MATCH(title,description,keywords) 
                   AGAINST ('$search_str' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score FROM pages 
                   WHERE MATCH(title, description,keywords) 
                   AGAINST ('$search_str' IN BOOLEAN MODE) " . $mid_str . " active = 'Yes' ORDER BY score DESC"; 


}else// not search fetch rand by catid
    $query_spages = "SELECT * FROM pages where " . preg_match("^ and", "", $mid_str) . " active = 'Yes' and catID = '" . $_REQUEST['id'] . "' ORDER BY mid DESC";   

mysql_select_db($database_myconn, $myconn);
$spages = mysql_query($query_spages, $myconn) or die(mysql_error());
//$row_spages = mysql_fetch_assoc($spages);

unset($settings);
$settings = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('select * from settings where id = 1',$myconn));

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

preg_match expects a start and an end of the regular expression.
For example `preg_match("/^ and/", "", $mid_str)`.

In your case, `^` is taken as start delimiter but the regex does not end with `^` so you get an error. Start and end delimiter can be anything, but most likely `/`is used to not clash with other specially treated characters.

Also, you probably mixed up `preg_match`and `preg_replace`. I think you want to `preg_replace`here, p.e.

`$query_spages = "SELECT * FROM pages where " . preg_replace("/^ and/", "", $mid_str) . " active = 'Yes' and catID = '" . $_REQUEST['id'] . "' ORDER BY mid DESC";`

Comment: Glad I could help :) Just a minor hint there. Don't forget to [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) everything you like to add to a query from outside world like `$_REQUEST`. Otherwise you'd be vulnerable to [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).